# How to find the largest white pixel region from a binary image

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I have been working on a binary image on opencv python. I need to get the largest region. I have used following code, but I am not getting desired output.

```
edged = cv2.Canny(im_bw, 35, 125)
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
c = max(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea)
```

Comment: Could you please provide some examples?

Comment: What do you mean by desired output? It gives you a segment that is not the largest?

Comment: Suppose I want to extract elephant from a binary image,in an assumption that elephant is the largest white pixel region.

Comment: @Kaira , sorry for being late, I suggest to use DoGs (difference of gaussians) that is being used by SIFT and SURF algorithms. You can also use watersheds as well.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the canny output to do this. Just do `findContours` on `im_bw` directly and you should get the desired results. If still not what you want, try to use different threshold values (given that your original image isn't BW itself)

```
(_, im_bw) = threshold(frame, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(im_bw.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
c = max(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea)
```

Comment: Thank u Thesane,, but it didnt worked, Can you please explain how to display "c', I get error on that portion,,                                                                                                 `image = cv2.drawContours(im_bw, [cnt], 0, (0,255,0), 3)
                                                                                        cv2.imshow('IMG',image) `

Comment: `drawContours` doesn't return an image (check documentation), it draws it over `im_dw`. In order to display it use `cv2.imshow('IMG', im_bw)`. also to draw the largest contours `c` use `cv2.drawContours(im_bw, [c], 0, (0,255,0), 3)`

Answer (score 0):

You really didn't explain what are you looking for,"largest region"? The code you posted will give you the largest contour found but you need to understand what is an OpenCV contour [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html#gsc.tab=0). Now depending of your image you can have a lot of noise and that makes OpenCV gives you not the "region" you are expecting, so you need to reduce the noise. Before apply the Canny or the threshold you can apply [BLUR](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html#gsc.tab=0) to the image, [EROTION and/or DILATION](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html).

The algorithm should be like this:

- Get the frame / image
- Grayscale it
- Apply Blur / Erode / Dilate to reduce noise
- Apply Canny or threshold
- Find contours
- Get the largest
- Do what you need

[Here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html?highlight=contour) you'll find good documentation in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `scikit-image` package of python which measures the area of the islands and chooses the largest area as follows -

```
import skimage
from skimage import measure

labels_mask = measure.label(input_mask)                       
regions = measure.regionprops(labels_mask)
regions.sort(key=lambda x: x.area, reverse=True)
if len(regions) > 1:
    for rg in regions[1:]:
        labels_mask[rg.coords[:,0], rg.coords[:,1]] = 0
labels_mask[labels_mask!=0] = 1
mask = labels_mask
```

Input image -

[image]

Output image -

[image]